# Rails: Piggyback on a touch: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that `has_one :thing, touch: true`. Occasionally, when that model is saved, it needs to update a value in `thing` in an `after_save` callback. This results in two database writes, one for the updated value from `after_save`, and another from the touch, updating the `updated_at` field.

Is there anyway for me to piggyback on the touch, and say "also update this other field to this other value"?